# Error on Select item in navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-maps-v2

I have a navigation drawer and when i click in the items i open the corrispondent fragment.. In one item i created a map that extends `FragmentActivity` and not `Fragment` so i think this is the cause of crash.. Anyway this is the log:

```
05-21 10:11:39.245: E/AndroidRuntime(22265): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 10:11:39.245: E/AndroidRuntime(22265): Process: com.tutecentral.navigationdrawer, PID: 22265
05-21 10:11:39.245: E/AndroidRuntime(22265): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 10:11:39.245: E/AndroidRuntime(22265):    at com.tutecentral.navigationdrawer.MainActivity.SelectItem(MainActivity.java:264)
05-21 10:11:39.245: E/AndroidRuntime(22265):    at com.tutecentral.navigationdrawer.MainActivity$DrawerItemClickListener.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:325)
05-21 10:11:39.245: E/AndroidRuntime(22265):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
05-21 10:11:39.245: E/AndroidRuntime(22265):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
05-21 10:11:39.245: E/AndroidRuntime(22265):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
05-21 10:11:39.245: E/AndroidRuntime(22265):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
05-21 10:11:39.245: E/AndroidRuntime(22265):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-21 10:11:39.245: E/AndroidRuntime(22265):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-21 10:11:39.245: E/AndroidRuntime(22265):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-21 10:11:39.245: E/AndroidRuntime(22265):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5144)
05-21 10:11:39.245: E/AndroidRuntime(22265):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 10:11:39.245: E/AndroidRuntime(22265):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-21 10:11:39.245: E/AndroidRuntime(22265):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
```

This is the nav drawer onClick in the items part:

```
public void SelectItem(int possition) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        FragmentActivity mapFragment = null;
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        switch (possition) {
            /*case 0:
                fragment = new FragmentThree();
                args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                               .getItemName());
                args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList
                            .get(possition).getImgResID());

                break;*/

        case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
            args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList
                    .get(possition).getImgResID());

            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        case 3:
            //-- Mappe e tratte
            mapFragment = new mapFragment();

            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
            args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList
                    .get(possition).getImgResID());
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new UserProfile();
                /*args.putString(UserProfile.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
                args.putInt(UserProfile.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());*/
            /*Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserProfile.class);
            startActivity(in);*/
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
            args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList
                    .get(possition).getImgResID());
            break;
        case 7:
            fragment = new aboutFragment();

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        fragment.setArguments(args);        
        FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();  
        frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                .commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(possition, true);

        //mDrawerList.getChildAt(possition).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.activated_background);
        setTitle(dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }
```

in the line 264 there is this: `fragment.setArguments(args);` and if is necessary i post the map fragment too:

```
public class mapFragment extends FragmentActivity  {
    // ...
  static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
          static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
          private GoogleMap map;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapfragment, null, false);

        InitialiseMap();

        Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
                .title("Hamburg"));
            Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(KIEL)
                .title("Kiel")
                .snippet("Kiel is cool")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

            // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);

        //...

        return v;
    }
    private void InitialiseMap() {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (map == null) {
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                                  .getMap();

        if (map != null) {


            }
         }
    }

}
```

How can i solve?

Comment: If it's an activity, then it needs to be launched using Intent

Comment: It's a `fragmentActivity`, i think also with intent it will crashes for the same reason. Take a look here: `fragment.setArguments(args);        
        FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();  
        frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                .commit();` i think it's all here the problem. I need to find a way to start for example an activity or something else and not only Fragments

Comment: You can't launch an activity like this. Intent is required for that. Have you tried with Intent?

Comment: The best way i think would be extends the map fragment as `Fragment` but it gets me errors casting `SupportFragmentManager` and i tried in many ways but i can't solve it! Anyway, i try with a simple intent to start the activity.. but i don't think it could go :)

Comment: Do you use support library? appCompat7?

Comment: nope i use the support.v4 library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54098/discussion-between-dhaval-and-end-game).